# What happened to the "TagLib#" library?

Tags: c#, mp3, id3, taglib-sharp

What is the current status of TagLib# (TagLib sharp)?

The official homepage www.taglib-sharp.com (link removed due to the NSFW nature of the new site that's parked at that address. -BtL) doesn't exist anymore!

I've found the project on [ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/p/5598) where the old homepage is still linked. Also the download link points to the old site.

BUT the ohloh development pages are linked to a mono-project [SVN repository](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/trunk/taglib-sharp), which seems to be under active development (last commit date: 2009/02/20, current version number: 2.0.3.2).

Furthermore, on the [developer.novell.com wiki](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp) the same SVN repo is linked.

So, is there any **up-to-date homepage** or, at least, any **up-to-date binary+documentation releases**?

Comment: In a recent post on his long-defunct blog, Brian Nickel, the original author, mentions the places that the Banshee team is supporting the library: 

Downloads (even Windows still!): http://download.banshee-project.org/taglib-sharp/
Bug Reporting: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=taglib-sharp
Source Code Repository: http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/taglib-sharp/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page at Novell (http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html) is no longer updated.

The source code is now hosted at https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp and the best way to install and use the latest version is using NuGet. Open the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and type:

```
PM> Install-Package taglib
```

This question is also answered at [TagLib# Windows distribution? Or another good ID3 reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181445/taglib-windows-distribution-or-another-good-id3-reader)

Comment: There was a new binary release (v2.2.0, july 2019) on : https://www.nuget.org/packages/TagLibSharp

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it moved here: http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html

Comment: To download, click the link to the homepage(http://download.banshee-project.org/taglib-sharp/), then the link to the latest version (2.0.3.7), and then there's taglib-sharp-2.0.3.7-windows.zip in there.

Comment: The latest version is 2.1.0.0 since 2012-Jul-03. It seems that actually no one really maintain it?

Answer (score 0):

As everyone seems to focus on the release versions either from NuGet or Novell, I'd simply suggest you to download the whole project from GitHub to get the latest version.

1. Open up the solution
2. Build -> BuildSolution
3. Use the class library in your project

I hope not everyone is still loading the old binaries, there is a wider support of container formats (opus \o/) in newer versions, as well as fixes and one or another additional supported tag.