# TagLib# Windows distribution? Or another good ID3 reader?

Tags: vb.net, id3, taglib-sharp

I wanted to write a quick program to get the file organization of my MP3 files back into sync with the info in my ID3 tags...

I had tried to get the Windows Media Format SDK, but when I go to install it says it can only run on WinXP. I found someone on here suggest TagLib#, which looked REALLY good, from the code examples. Problem is it seems the official site is gone, and the other links I've found to a hosting on Novell's servers is also down.

Anyone know where I can still get a distro of TagLib# for C#/VB.NET for Windows? Or another good ID3 tag reader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the source and DLL here: http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.0.4.0/taglib-sharp-2.0.4.0-windows.zip

You can check http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/ to see the latest version.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will have to check this out. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend installing taglib-sharp with NuGet. NuGet is the best and easiest way to use opensource libraries in Visual Studio.

To install TagLib#, run the following command in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

```
PM> Install-Package taglib
```

The NuGet distribution of taglib-sharp can be found at http://nuget.org/packages/taglib.
The official source code repository is at https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an svn checkout of the code from http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/trunk/taglib-sharp.

Comment: Is there a way to get an actual project out of that... a zip maybe, without having to individually download a dozen files? Is that something with SVN somehow? I am not familiar with that at all.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an individual file or even source package for taglib-sharp at the moment.  The easiest way to get the source will probably be to download and install tortoisesvn from http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.  From there you can run the checkout command on the url from the post.